# How to round up a number to the next 10 in SQL Server?

Tags: sql

What I need is 17,522 rounds up to 17,530. Also 17,525 rounds to 17,530. And 17,529 rounds up to 17,530 as well. I want everything up to next 10.

Comment: There's something called Google!!!!!!

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1589/sql-server-rounding-functions--round-ceiling-and-floor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select floor((X + 9) / 10) * 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 10 * ((a+9)/10)
from (values (17522), (17525), (17529)) as t(a)
```

Comment: This is not decimal safe in a use case of 17522.7 for example.